# Jade: How to include a javascript file

Tags: express, pug

I need to include a javascript file to webpage. I write the following:

```
include /../scripts/jquery.timeago.js
```

but I get

```
<script>/*
 * timeago: a jQuery plugin, version: 0.8.2 (2010-02-16)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.3 or later
 *
 * Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to support automatically
 * updating fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago").
 *
 * For usage and examples, visit:
 * http://timeago.yarp.com/
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008-2010, Ryan McGeary (ryanonjavascript -[at]- mcgeary [*dot*] org)
 */
(function($) {
....
</script>
```

as result. But I need:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How to do it?

Comment: [`includes`](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) is used for including the content of one pug file into another. `script` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Put this in your jade file:

`script(src="/Scripts/jquery.timeago.js")`

Comment: Don't forget to put it at the end of your `<body>` tag and not in your `<head>` to make the page load faster

Answer (score 11):

You can put this code in your jade file:

```
   script(type='text/javascript' src='public/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js')
```

Answer (score 10):

Also, if you would like to include inline js within your jade file you could do the following as well:

```
script(type="text/javascript").
console.log('hello world');
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for Adding scripts to your jade files is

```
script(src="",...,otherAttribute="")
```

example like the one below, that adds Jquery Bootstraps to the page.

```
  script( src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js",  integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" ,crossorigin="anonymous")

script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js", integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q", crossorigin="anonymous")

  script( src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ,integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl", crossorigin="anonymous")
```

Comment: Posting code only is a bit rude and not very helpful. Do you mind to explain? And may add a link to the documentation?

Comment: so sorry, I was just in a hurry, 
the syntax for adding scripts in Jade 
script(src="",...,otherAttribute="")
And can be added to anywhere in the Html page,

But codes above is just a quick way to add Jquery for bootstrap, and its best to add it just before the closing body tag.